# Is there a fixed point theorem that applies to $f: \sum_k x_k 10^k \mapsto \sum_k x_k!$?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, $f:x=\sum_k x_k 10^k \mapsto \sum_k x_k!$ where $x_k$ is the $k$-th digit of $x$ in base ten. This function came up in a Project Euler problem. The question is which numbers are the sums of the factorials of their own digits, i.e. $x$ such that $f(x)=x$, i.e. the fixed points.

There are two nontrivial fixed points, 145 and 40585. I'm wondering if this can be shown *without* a brute force search. There is a cutoff since $f(x) < x$ when $x$ is greater than about 6 digits since $\sum_k x_k! < \sum_k 9! = N*9! < 10^N$ where $N$ is the number of digits.

A cursory search through a list of fixed point theorems didn't reveal one whose conditions $f$ meets. $f$ is not a contraction mapping nor monotonic. Iterating $f^k$ seems to converge to a handful of small cycles of order 3 or so.

Comment: Is there a policy that discourages discussion of Project Euler questions in MO?

Comment: There seems to be a bigger issue; every fixed point theorem I know of requires a connected/manifold domain. I'd say Z being discrete is a far bigger issue (I'd say insurmountable) than lack of contraction. For instance, even if f were monotone, I don't see why it would help in this setting.

Comment: The Project Euler part was just finding the fixed points, which can be done by brute force. There seem to be some discrete fixed point theorems, but I don't think they apply: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_fixed-point_theorem